# Is there any AI apis that can remember your information?

Tags: api, computer-programming, conversational-ai

As someone who is between the beginner and intermediate brackets in terms of programming, and fairly new AI apis, can someone help point me in the right direction? I want to program a chatbot/AI assistant. However, I want this bot to be able to retain personal information, and previous conversations. For example, I want to tell it I drive (for example, a F-150) and then a week later be able to ask it to search for “replacement tires for my vehicle” is there anything like that out there that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways to handle the conversational history, but one mainstream method is that you as the application developer handle this. for example, you send to the LLM api the following (the part in square brackets is the response):

```
user: I drive a Ford F-150
bot: [...some text-generation i.e. "this is a decent vehicle"]
```

then, I week later, you enter your prompt to *your own system* which in turn sends the following to the LLM api (the part in square brackets is the response):

```
user: I drive a Ford F-150
bot: this is a decent vehicle
user: replacement tires for my vehicle
bot: [...some text-generation with the context of Fort F-150 i.e.  "Ford F-150's 17-inch wheels come with 235/65R17 103H all-season tire can be bought in auto-depot"]
```

so in essence, it's your responsibility to keep, manage the assemble the chat history before you send it to the LLM AI api.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, last night I think I found what I am looking for. I found a video by networkchuck (https://youtu.be/WxYC9-hBM_g?si=Xs36HjXk0G4yOjnQ) I haven’t set it up yet or even really looked into it, but it sounds promising.